# Detect Blackberry pre OS 7

Tags: mobile, blackberry, mobile-website, browser-detection, sniffing

I need to be able to detect if my webpage is running on a blackberry before OS 7.

I need to be able to tell a user that certain elements will no function correctly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the useragent, you can detect what device the user is using.

You can use this great link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862

A sample user agent for the BlackBerry Bold 9900 smartphone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9900; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0 Mobile Safari/534.11+
```